# Member function as default property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I understand the new syntax to specify default properties on a React / ReactNative component is specifying a class property 'defaultProps'. I am facing a scenario where this proves to be problematic (unless I'm unaware of something, hence my question).

I want to specify an onLayout handler in a View (a base class for other Views in my app). Now this onLayout handler would have to call any base class implementations after doing it's own stuff.

I can do the simple thing:

```
MyBaseView.defaultProps: { onLayout: () => {console.log('hello from onlayout');}}
```

But since this is a 'class context' I don't have access to any 'this' here, hence I can't call any subclass implementation here.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Maybe is not the right approach, if you want a component to perform some functionality and then call another component, I think is better to use high order component for that.

Comment: ok thanks, sounds like a good idea